# Network Printers

Tags: networking, printing

We have a sever that shares all the printers. The PC's that are running on XP professional get a error message quoting (Connect to Printer). The only way I can find to get around the problem is by restating the printer and as soon is it comes online you can then add it but you have not got long. do you think it could be anything to-do with updates on the sever?

the sever system is running Windows Server 2003

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The printers aren't sharing the same IP address are they? Have the drivers been updated on the server recently by adding a new printer? Do the printers have static IP address' or not? There's lots of questions and variables to why a printer doesnt work on a network

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I think you should connect the printer to one of the XP machines to see if one of those machines has the same problem.   I'd bet you've got some kind of Windows Server 2003 policy/permission issue of some kind and putting the printer on another computer would answer that question really quick.